# What is considered to be the most difficult sound for native English speakers to pronounce?

Tags: pronunciation

When I was first learning Chinese, I found the `e4 - 饿` & `ü3/ü4 - 女/绿` sounds to be the most problematic.

Has there been any research into this? If so, what sounds are generally the most problematic sounds for an initially monolingual English speaker to learn when studying Chinese?

Comment: it depends on which region the person comes from. People from south part (Guangdong, Guangxi for ex.) usually have difficulty with zh, ch ans sh, while those from middle part(Sichuan, Hunan) cannot pronounce L, so they replace it by n.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking about people who can initially speak only English who are learning Mandarin.

Comment: 俄 is e2, and 女 nv3 绿 lv4.

Comment: My bad, I meant `饿`

Comment: these should be 餓 for hungry and 綠 for green.

Comment: @Rony simplified hungry = 饿, simplified green = 绿

Comment: @gonnastop If you are familiar with British English, you can use the FUR vowel in Received Pronunciation as a substitute for 饿...

Comment: For me it's more a problem of distinguishing sounds in speech than reproducing individual sounds in isolation. Especially the ones that sound like English's *schwa*. Other people have more trouble with unaspirated consonants. Also it depends whether you regard tones to be sounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about research

From experience the sounds that people have the most issues with are:

- the "r" sound when used at the beginning of a word. Best examples are 热 (re) and 日 (ri).
- differentiating between zh & j, sh & x, ch & q.
- the ü sound as in 魚 fish (I think that is the one you mentioned).

Comment: You're right about `r`, I remember having trouble with that as well

Comment: I'd add z/c/s as well :). A friend of mine who is learning Mandarin has a lot of trouble even differentiating between them.

Comment: @JamesJiao yes this is true - in first year I remember a lot of people just couldn't tell. Also s/sh

Comment: To be fair, plenty of Chinese people don't differentiate s and sh, and Chongqing people pronounce 'r-' as a voiced 's-' (IPA's [z], not pinyin's z). 如果 = zu guo.

Comment: I have found in the case of differentiating s and sh that tone seems to play a lot more importance.  If you look at the obious example of 4 and 10 si[4] and shi[2] you can say si[2] for ten and they will understand with no problem, because they seem to listen for the tone more than the actual sound.

Comment: For most of our English-speaker students, "r" is really hard. Our rule of thumb for our students to acquire it naturally is listen, imitate and practice, but not refer to any sounds in English, which would be confusing and sometimes misleading. After all English sounds and Chinese sounds are quite different in many ways!

Answer (score 2):

To be native,

for Mandarin Chinese speakers, the most difficult is tongue rolling heavy gesture, which defacto necessary.

for Yue Chinese, the most difficult is its variety of tones over every languages.

Hardiest is Yue Chinese.